# using package Azure/go-ntlmssp to authenticate sharepoint results 401

Tags: authentication, go, ntlm, sharepoint-api

i have used package like github.com/Azure/go-ntlmssp to authenticate to sharepoint 2010.

```html
url, username, password := "http://www.some-website.com", "admin", "12345"

client := &http.Client{
    Transport: ntlmssp.Negotiator{
        RoundTripper:&http.Transport{},
    },
}

req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
req.SetBasicAuth(username, password)

res, _ := client.Do(req)
```

in response i am getting 401 Unauthorized
Now here the wierd thing is sometimes(after many trials and not consistent after that also) the authentication happens successfully.
And when the authentication fails in response header i can see Www-Authenticate:[NTLM].
Please suggest